# Can Spotify iOS SDK access offline tracks

Tags: spotify

Is it possible to access tracks offline using the Spotify iOS SDK? I haven't managed to find any documentation or examples that show how this is possible.

Some [old questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11347903/5135551) indicate it is available in the [deprecated LibSpotifylibrary](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/) but it is strongly recommended to use the new [Spotify iOS SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/) instead.

There is a request for [Android Offline Playback](https://github.com/spotify/android-sdk/issues/2) but even that is almost 2 years old, and nothing I have found about the iOS SDK.

Comment: any updates on that buddy?

Comment: Sorry, but no updates. I haven't yet found a way to access offline tracks for Spotify. I may start a bounty as was suggested when we get back to this.

Comment: what i have found out is, that spotify is caching tracks. what would be interesting for me then is, what tracks have been cached? so that i can at least display THAT information....

Comment: Agreed, but AFAIK I can't get to that information either, as that is part of the Spotify app and not available for other apps. I'm still investigating as well.

Comment: nono. not the offline tracks from the spotify app. that will because of the sandbox mode, never be possible. but it caches the tracks within our apps. the tracks that have been played automatically and then doesnt need to download again if played again. but i'd need a way to figure out what tracks are cached...

Comment: This is not supported in the iOS SDK. You can make feature requests here: https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/issues